# DSN-Less Connection from MS Access to MS SQL Server Listener

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm using MS Access O365 and have been using a [DSN-Less connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/access/create-dsn-less-connection-linkted-table) to link tables from a MS SQL Server 2019.  Now we've started using an Availability Group Listener to connect to instead of directly connecting to an individual server and to do that we've added the property "MultiSubnetFailover=Yes" to the connection string.  Unfortunately, the code referenced fails to connect to the listener about half the time with a timeout error, but connects to the individual servers correctly 100% of the time.

We had similar issues connecting to the same listener using Excel and a Microsoft OLE DB Provider based connection string until we added "Connect Timeout=60;" to it.  Since that was added though, it works every time.  Unfortunately, I see no way to increase the timeout on an ODBC based connection so I'm looking for any other options that might work.

**Editing my question based on what I've learned via comments below:**

I have a connection string that I use in Excel to connect to a SQL Server 2019 listener and it's working well:

```
"Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=MyServerListenerName,1234;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultiSubnetFailover=Yes;Connect Timeout=60;"
```

Can I use this as is or with some modification to attached sql tables in Access?  If so, how?

Comment: The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) that is included with Windows is a legacy driver, unaware of new features since SQL Server 2000. It doesn't support MultiSubnetFailover.  Install and use the newer [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server) (MSOLEDBSQL).

Comment: You probably need the current [ODBC Driver 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: If you must use the legacy driver that doesn't support MultiSubnetFailover, change the [RegisterAllIrovidersIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#RegisterAllProvidersIP) setting on the database server to 0 to support downlevel clients.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but the issue I'm having is with attaching sql server tables to access using a DSN-Less ODBC connection.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, but with v18 of the driver just being released a couple weeks ago, that really isn't an option for me as I'm in a large (slow) organization.  Also, I don't see anything in the v18 release notes regarding this issue.  I'll keep this in mind though and give it shot once it becomes available to me.

Comment: You don't have to use version 18.  You can use any version of the Microsoft ODBC Driver; just not the legacy SQL Server ODBC driver that's part of Windows.

Comment: @Todd, a DSN-less connection can use OLE DB or ODBC. Just make sure you're using a modern driver.

Comment: Ok.  So I feel like I've got a "duh" moment coming, but how can I attach SQL Server tables in Access using a DSN-Less, OLE DB based function?